# Android using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to start a fragment with using onclick function.How can I do this ? I am using this code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

I want create a function in mainactivity and when this function is run I want to change fragment.

Ps:I don't want to add this fragment to tabs.

Other codes(layout,tabs adapter etc):http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/#disqus_thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already know how to create the `Fragment` class, all you need to do is:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, new YourFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

`R.id.container` is the layout where you are adding the `Fragment`. It should be in you main.xml

**EDIT**

You need a container for your `Fragment` so in your xml you need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now when you add the `Fragment` it will be inflated inside of that container.

Comment: I am getting this error in eclipse:cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.fragmentmanager to android.app.fragmentmanager do you know how can I fix this ?

Comment: Change `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();` to `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Thank you it fixed but I have one more error :  The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments

             Code:fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.pager, new ChatsFragment());

Do you know this ?

Comment: `ChatsFragment` is extending `Fragment`? also, what is `R.id.pager`? An empty layout or the 'id' of your `ViewPager`?

Comment: Yes ChatsFragment is extending Fragment. R.id.pager is in the activity_main.xml here:http://goo.gl/svon88

Comment: Ok that's the problem. `R.id.pager` can't be used as a fragment container, let me update my answer to show you what to do.

Comment: I added your edited code but when I try to start app it's crashing here is the log:http://prntscr.com/46af17

Comment: Did you use `ViewPager` or `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` on your xml? You should be using the second one. I updated my answer

Comment: Can you post your `Fragment` class?

Comment: I did but same http://prntscr.com/46ali1

Ps:By the way,thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I get it. In your `Fragment` class make sure you are importing `android.app.Fragment;` and not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: It's fixed but,I am getting another error now.Can you connect to my pc via teamviewer ? If we can fix this then we will write the solution to stackoverflow.Or I can send error to here ? Error in tabs adapter:http://prntscr.com/46aq6l (I tried remove support.v4 in this page but this raises another errors.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58021/discussion-between-carlosjimenez-and-tolgay-toklar).