# Android Studio two Activity in one

Tags: android

I got two Activitys. The `MainActivity` consists 4 Views (Left upper corner, right upper corner, left down corner, right down corner) which have the same size.
And now I like to show the other `Activity` in one of the Views in the `MainActivity`. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Fragment's mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033602/how-to-use-fragments-in-android,  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24960984/5529263,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871666/android-using-fragments-programmatically

Comment: The best thing you can do is using 4 framelayout, like you said (Left upper corner, right upper corner, left down corner, right down corner).  Using one activity, you can inflate 4 fragment inside the 4 framelayout. Each fragment, like an activity, have their own view and events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments here its link https://github.com/codepath/android-fragment-basics

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the android's Fragments. They're just like Activities with the lifecycle and all.

But they have a tiny difference. These fragments don't have a context and use their parent's (Activity's).

Here's the google developers' link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?gclid=CjwKCAjw-OHkBRBkEiwAoOZql8XKwf9Qt_Rj4Z9Vepeg2DOUs3Hl0AaYPQHQ1QBSnTfW5C2NltaAhRoCBY4QAvD_BwE